# Why BNB Chain is not working?

Tags: binance, binance-smart-chain

My transactions on BNB Chain are not going through. My BNB Chain node is not syncing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [BNB Chain is currently paused](https://www.bnbchain.org/en/blog/bnb-chain-ecosystem-update/) due to a hack related to Binance bridge

- It is paused only for this hack (not other hacks)
- It is not clear how it can be paused in the first place
- There is no timeline when it will start work again